# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'lenovo'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql

I have to use MySQL with python. for that, I am trying to install MySQL in linux and try to connect it to the server. for that I followed these steps:

```
sudo apt install mysql-server  
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

after that, I run mysql command in the terminal it worked fine.

then I make file .py as:

```
import mysql.connector

# Connect to server

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    port=3306,
    user="root",
    password="123")

print(mydb)
```

Error:

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lenovo/Pictures/hatchery system/charts/s.py", line 4, in <module>
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
  File "/home/lenovo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 286, in connect
    return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lenovo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/home/lenovo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1095, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/home/lenovo/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 268, in _open_connection
    raise get_mysql_exception(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

after that when I run mysql in the terminal it cause this Error.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'lenovo'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

NOTE: I have tried several solutions but if I solve one error on the next step it causes another error. Now i am stuck here.

EDIT:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem
import mysql.connector as mc

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(650, 500)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.lineEdit_dbname = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineEdit_dbname.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_dbname.setObjectName("lineEdit_dbname")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_dbname)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.lineEdit_tblname = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineEdit_tblname.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_tblname.setObjectName("lineEdit_tblname")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_tblname)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.tableWidget.setFont(font)
        self.tableWidget.setLineWidth(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(200)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        # connect signal
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.select_data)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def select_data(self):
        dbname = self.lineEdit_dbname.text()
        tblname = self.lineEdit_dbname.text()
        try:
            mydb = mc.connect(
            host = "localhost",
            user = "root",
            password = "$Aman028",
            database = dbname
            )

            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            mycursor.excute("SELECT * FROM {}".format(tblname))

            result = mycursor.fetchall()
            self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)

            for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
                self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)

                for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number,column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))

        except mc.Error as e:
            print("Error occured")

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Database Name:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Table Name:"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "ID"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Username"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Show Data"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

port 3307 is selected

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

Comment: It says you have not supplied a password.  Did you misspell the `password` argument in your code?  It also says you supplied `user=lenovo`.  The traceback is obviously NOT from the code you posted; the traceback is assigning to `cnx`, not to `mydb`.  It's hard to help you without the actual code.

Comment: Also make sure your MySQL is configured to allow network access.  Can you get in with the command line `mysql` tool?

Answer (score 1):

Your first error from Python says you tried to log in as `root` and that you supplied a password, but that username/password combo is incorrect.

Your second error from the terminal says you tried to log in as a *different user*, `lenovo`, with *no password* (you have to add `-p` to use a password) and that was also incorrect.

We can't tell you what your MySQL username and password are, you'll have to figure that out or reset the database.

[This tutorial](https://itslinuxfoss.com/install-set-up-mysql-database-ubuntu-22-04/) may help, particularly running mysql_secure_installation to reset the root password.

Comment: yesterday I have done all steps in your given link and mysql was running well. then i install xamp and run it, and in  phpmyadmin i created a table and write a script in python to connect to mysql and retrieve data from phpmysql. and it's just not connected. than i tried to run mysql on terminal it show this error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'lenovo'@'localhost' (using password: NO) , kindly see edit in the post.

Comment: in mysql_secure_installation I. have changed my password.

Comment: @samannaz You need to log into MySQL with the correct username and password. `sudo mysql` runs the MySQL client *as root*, but with *no password* so it doesn't work. You don't need `sudo` to run `mysql`, your MySQL login is different from your shell login. Do `mysql -u<your mysql username> -p` and it will prompt you to enter a password. No `sudo`, and be sure to use `-p` so it asks you for a password (yes, it's silly the default is to not use a password). Be sure to give it the password for that MySQL user.

Comment: @samannaz Here is a demonstration. https://gist.github.com/schwern/15aa97c51e883da471c2b1f60fbe709d

Comment: I am facing further problems in it. please refer to this link https://gist.github.com/schwern/15aa97c51e883da471c2b1f60fbe709d

Comment: @samannaz 0) You don't need to reinstall. 1) ***Your login account is different from your MySQL account***. You're trying to connect to MySQL as "lenovo", but there is no MySQL account called "lenovo". If you want to log into MySQL as "lenovo" you need to make a MySQL user called "lenovo". 2) `sudo mysql` is a security risk. Use `mysql -u root -p` to log in as the root MySQL user. 3) Burn that password you just posted to the Internet.